# Crear una función en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla llamada Oferta con estas variables.

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Quiero crear una función llamada caducado, que conpruebe si la fecha actual supera a la variable fecha_limite. Para ello, escribo lo siguiente en el fichero Oferta.php:

```
public function caducado(){
    return strtotime($this->fecha_limite)<strtotime(date("d-m-Y")); // Si devuelve verdadero, es que la oferta ha caducado al pasar la fecha limite.
}
```

Deberia ahora poder usar `$oferta->caducado`, sin embargo, me sale un mensaje de error de que solo se admiten relaciones en ese fichero (y mira que si he podido crear funciones que devuelven rutas).
¿Como consigo que se admita la función?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si este método está en un modelo tenés que llamar al método haciendo **`$oferta->caducado()`** de lo contrario espera que sea una relación o un accessor.

Comment: Pues asi he logrado que funcione. Es decir, si la función es para acceder a una clave foranea no necesito el parentesis al final, pero si es de otro tipo si.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que esta función está en el modelo.

Lo que pretendes es crear un **accessor** y lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
public function getCaducadoAttribute(){
        return strtotime($this-> fecha_limite)<strtotime(date("d-m-Y")); // Si devuelve verdadero, es que la oferta ha caducado al pasar la fecha limite.
    }
```

En la [documentación de Laravel (Español)](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) lo tienes.